# how can we find $near in $look up aggregation pipeline using mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

exports.getnearby=async(req,res)=>{

const long=req.body.long;

```
const lat=req.body.long;
const nearest=await productModellang.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two collections one is product in which I'm storing price,image and location and another collection in which I'm storing _id of product collection as product_id and other details of products .Now I want to find product and it's details on basis of location from both collections.I'm unable to post my whole code.

Comment: It's urgent any idea will be apreciated.